# How do I iterate through excel cells using C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2013

I need to know how to iterate through excel cells using C#.

I have a Data Table that I use to export data to an existing Excel file. I need to be able to search for values that only equal "tel:" and "email:".
These values will only be in the second column in excel.

Here is my code sequence. Please let me know what I am doing wrong or if there is a better way.

```
int rowNum = 1;

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell in ws.Rows[rowNum, 2])
{
    if (cell.Value = "tel:")
    {
        ws.Rows[rowNum].Delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: `=` doesn't mean what you apparently think it does.

Comment: There must be an error whats the error?

Comment: I know. It should be "==" but I keep getting a error COMException was unhandled

Comment: Yes David, it throws an error I stated above

Comment: Have you stepped through it whilst debugging and worked out which line gives the error?

Comment: yes it doesn't even iterate, as soon as it hits the loop it throws the error

Comment: Are you trying to remove the data from the Excel file before you export or after you export? Also what is `ws`, the WorkSheet? Where does your DataTable link into the code?

Comment: Bernd, its after the export. And yes "ws" is the Worksheet. So, my DataTable is pulling data from my database and I am looping through each row in the DataTable to place data into a specific cell in excel. I hope that made since.

Comment: Then why not stop the export of "tel" and "email" cells? That way you don't need to touch the excel file again.

Comment: Bernd, Its more of a formatting issue. For instance, a couple of the values in my DataTable is the phone number and email. Some records in the database may not have a phone number or a email address. So, when I am formatting the excel file I will have a string of "tel:" before the actual phone number. i.e. tel: xxx-xxx-xxxx. Same for  email. When there is no phone number or email I am left with just "tel:" or "email:" I want to delete those rows that only have those values of "tel:" and "email:" with nothing behind them. I hope this makes since.

Comment: do you have blank cells in your excel workbook?  what is the actual error message you receive?

Comment: Hi Sorceri, I figured it out. I did it at the DataTable level. If a dataTable Value doesn't have a value then don't insert.